# How to ensure JS in header runs before script in body in Django app

Tags: javascript, fetch, django-staticfiles, python-django-storages

I have an application, where in the body I initialize a component based on [apache echarts library](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html). This page needs 2 json files. One for the map data and another is geoJSON file for the map. On the page, echarts library is loaded in script. I add another JS that loads geoJSON file from a URL. In the body, then I initiate echart component and provide the map data json file. But because of asynchronous nature, the page does not render the map in first attempt, but on refresh again (without disabling cache), it then renders. Reason is simple(I think) as geoJSON is large file(1.2MB) and it takes time. By the time it downloads, the echart component in the body is already executed and it fails to render.

pseudo code for the page is

```
<head>
<script src= cdn.echarts.js> </script>
<script src=loadgeoJSON.js> </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='echart'> </div>

<script>
var echartsInstance = echarts.init(
        document.getElementById("echart"));
      
fetch(link)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    echartsInstance.setOption(data)
  });

</script>
```

and js to load geoJSON is

```
const world_map_url = "url to json file";

fetch(world_map_url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((jsondata) => {
    echarts.registerMap('world', jsondata)
  });
```

I can think of 2 ways to solve it.

1. Speed up geoJSON load somehow 1.2MB vs 20kb?
2. Ensure than JS in header that loads geoJSON finishes before body chart are rendered.

I am not sure how to achieve those however.

for case 1

My web app is running on [Django with static files configured with AWS S3 storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).
is there a way that I can also serve geoJSON from Django's local filesystem? I am hoping that way file will be loaded faster or maybe there is a way to preload that file in JS?

I have same similar issue on Angular as well. In that case solution was to import geoJSON
file as an object inside the typescript as calling from a URL was producing the same issue.

for case 2

this is surely not just Django issue, but in general for other such problems. I am no JS expert to figure out how to get this dependency ensured? Especially as on 1 page there may be multiple charts that would use same geoJSON that just need to be loaded once for all those charts? I can only guess that I am not the first one to face this issue, but searching online mostly pointing to me to use fetch.then or with jquery $.get.then. But, maybe I am not using them the right way.

Any help or pointer would be helpful.

Thanks

EDIT 1: Crude solution

but this now means every page needs to know about maps registration.
There may be that number of maps may change e.g. world map, USA map etc.

Is it possible to somehow put map registrations separate from charts, while still ensuring that charts render after this map registration?

page script has full chain of calls

```
link = "url to datajson";

var echartsInstance = echarts.init(
        document.getElementById("echart"));

 if (geojson not registered) {
   fetch(geojsonurl).
   .then(geojsonr => geojsonr.json())
    .then(geojson => register this geojson)
     .then( (r) => fetch(link))
      .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((data) => {
           echartsInstance.setOption(data)
     });
  }else{
    fetch(link)
      .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((data) => {
           echartsInstance.setOption(data)
     });
}
```

Comment: Unless the script tag has `async` or `defer`, it's run synchronously in order.

Comment: But `fetch()` is asynchronous. There's no way for a later script to wait for that to complete.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for confirming my understanding. loading script tag in sequence, does not help in this case. as it is about what is done by those scripts. Question remains, how is such situation handled in general? I am new to all this django, JS and so on, so would appreciate, any pointers. In think in general there is a parent resource that needs to be loaded, which would be needed by 1 or more other components later on. how to ensure those components trigger after this parent resource is loaded? is there some way of subscribing to "finish" event or so?

Comment: One crude way I found is to sequence both fetch in single chain. I have updated main question to show the change. but that does not seem right approach as then I am forcing  to load geojson for each echart component. also the fact that every other page now needs to care about geoJSON details rather than defering to a central function.

Comment: Also, if the other way to probably solve it as mentioned in original thread. i.e. to how to use geojson file from local storage from Django server rather than fetching from a URL. that may work as it would be faster even if async.